# How to customize 19.10 Desktop Icon Font Size

Tags: fonts, gnome-shell, 19.10, desktop-icons

I'm searching how to customize the desktop icons font size on Ubuntu 19.10 GNOME (standard) edition. For example, i Want 8px.

With 18.04, it was as simple as

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Ubuntu 8'
```

On 19.10, there is no `org.gnome.nautilus.desktop` schemadir.
I searched inside all  parameters `gsettings list-recursively` and `dconf dump /`, cannot find any related to desktop icons font.

Comment: Do you require a CLI method, or can you use `gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: How desktop icons are handled is changed fundamentally. It's now handled by a GNOME Shell extension instead of Nautilus, that's why the old solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***as a Admin or for system-wide***

edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/stylesheet.css`

```
.name-label {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

I have already edited above part. I have added the line `font-size: 40px;` and changed the color to green.

[image]

Another Customization Image:

[image]

---

***For local changes (with out need of root privileges)***

follow this  [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233041/20-04-how-to-change-the-size-and-appearance-of-desktop-icons-and-the-way-they/1233252?noredirect=1#comment2076629_1233252)  and edit the contents like below in the `stylesheet.css` file.

```
.name-label {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;       
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Currently, desktop icons are managed by an extension, so currently, the only way to change font sizes is to hard-edit the .css of the extension. It would be better if a local .css could be edited - then no root is required and change applies only to current user. Cannot test as I have no Gnome anymore.

Comment: @vanaduim i llike your comment because your pointing exactly where im digging : could i locally overlay the current theme in order to choose the font size from where the extension apply the 3 ratios 'small', 'normal' and 'big'

Comment: @cmak.fr Answer Edited for local capability. Thanks