# Modify an icon on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

I put a normal html file as a link on my desktop.
It has a basic icon, which I would like to modify, how can I do so?
PS: I was using a lovely sddm theme if it matters.

Comment: I use a different flavor of Ubuntu, and figured this would be an easy point and click operation. Nope... See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233041/20-04-how-to-change-the-size-and-appearance-of-desktop-icons-and-the-way-they). That should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, that is useful.