# Hide text under icons on desktop possible?

Tags: 21.04

I'm trying to hide the text/name of the desktop icons in the 21.04 version update.

Is that possible? I've looked around and I can't seem to find anything that's not outdated or working.
Thank you!

Comment: It Is possible by editing gnome shell extension desktop-icons

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1233252/739431 in similar way it's possible

Comment: thanks bois. I got inspired by those posts and actually installed Desktop icons extension, went into one of the files and added font-size:0px; to the code. works as a charm now

Answer (score 1):

No, this option is not build into the extension. It would probably require editing source code of the extension to remove the icon label.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i ended up installing this extension [Desktop Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2452/desktop-icons/)

and after installing I disabled the extension (it doubled my icons for some reason)

then i went into /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/stylesheet.css
and added font-size:0px; in line 2 and line 9
it now looks like this.

[image]

and my desktop icons look like this
[image]

Thanks for the support yall!