# Customize the right-click menu on the desktop in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments

How can I customize the right-click menu on the desktop in ubuntu 20.04?

also I am not using any desktop extension.

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: It is dead, dear @preIdiot. It is time to test MATE (see example of normal filemanager-desktop integration [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1263992/66509)) or Cinnamon as replacement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable default file manager(nautilus) to handle desktop icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263974/how-to-enable-default-file-managernautilus-to-handle-desktop-icons)

Comment: But when I use the default desktop icons extension it adds some new entries to the menu. when means it is customizable I guess

Comment: Are you looking for "Right Click Menu Customization" without extensions??

Comment: @UnKNOWn not specific... if there is an extension that allows it and doesn't change anything other than it then I will love to use it.

Comment: Ok actually by default in ubuntu the right click more options are from extension only. So renaming the extension and tweaking the js files will do what you want.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1233252/739431 something similar to this

Comment: yeah I found the contents of the menu in `desktopGrid.js` file

Comment: I can edit the extension for it but problem is that I don't want the icons to appear on the desktop and I don't know how to edit the extension to have that functionality

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1341298/739431