# Can I give filenames an opaque background on the desktop? They are hard to read against a busy wallpaper pattern

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, text, gsettings, transparency

[image]

In Ubuntu 20.10, it's hard to read the names of items on my desktop when I use a busy wallpaper background image. Can I change a setting or something to make the text blocks have an opaque background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following this post as a guide [How to customize 19.10 Desktop Icon Font Size](https://askubuntu.com/q/1185621/739431)

edit the `stylesheet.css` file to have a line like below

```
.name-label {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(3,5,2,0.2)
}
```

Observe this line, `background-color: rgba(3,5,2,0.2)`. edit the rgba color as you wish.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! After logging out and back in, that works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you r using `xorg` as display server.. Alt+f2 r enter is enough instead of relogin.. Thanks..

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Thanks again!